# change server name in message when installing ios application

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad, plist

I have an iOS app that can be installed via the web (in-house deployment).
When a user clicks on the link to install the application (itms-services ...) there is a message displayed in the following format:

"servername.domain.com" would like to install "application name"
with two buttons "install" and "Cancel".
My question, is there a way to change the server name in the message (which is usually server.domain.com) to another label of my own? I would like to put my company name instead.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change prompt message of itms-services installation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23544198/change-prompt-message-of-itms-services-installation)

Answer (score 1):

I highly doubt it.

This would raise security concerns, as you could change the name in the popup for, say, "Google Inc." and trick an user in installing a malicious app asking for its Google login and password.

Having the fully qualified domain name in the popup makes the users confirms that he/she trusts this domain. As Apple requires domains serving adhoc/entreprise apps to have a valid SSL certificate, this basically is the same as asking the user if he/she trusts the person/company holding the SSL cert (which if you paid enough will display your entreprise name -see https://apple.com).

A solution if you have an "ugly" domain name, would be to buy a more "user-friendly" one (eg. apps.mycompany.com or mycompanyapps.com). However this would probably also mean buying a new SLL cert.

Otherwise, in worst case scenario, educate your users on which domains can be trusted before prompting them to install the app (in your distribution emails or website for example).